# Sending clickable gps long/lat via SMS

Tags: android

In my app, I'm getting the user's location using this bit of code:

```
locationText = location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
```

...and I'm sending it to another user via SMS using this bit:

```
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, locationText, null, null);
```

... When the other user receives the txt, they get it as "longitude, latitude".  Either one is clickable but how would I format the string so when its received, it's clickable as a combined long/lat? I've tried removing the comma (,) but then none of it is clickable.  Google searching yielded only how to search using long/lat in google maps.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form url like following url link,

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=lat,lng

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know what terms I was missing in my google searches.  Hopefully this page will pop up for others in the future :)